# greenDAO schema generation with relative output path; failing with i/o not found

Tags: android, greendao

Following along with [this tutorial](http://blog.gaku.net/how-to-integrate-greendao-to-an-android-studio-project/), I've been able to create a working app module that compiles and runs, but fails if I pass a relative path to the generateAll method. It works fine if I specify an absolute path. My android studio project is composed of a few modules, structured like

project_root, with sub directories for each of it's modules

/daogenerator

/app

Each has it's own src directories, and I'm calling the generateAll like:

```
new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema,
                "../app/src");
```

which results in an io error, indicating that the directory doesn't exist. I've modified the path to many reasonable alternatives, and confirmed that the paths exist on disk, but still getting the error. The absolute path works fine, so I'm trying to understand what I'm missing to get it working with a relative path. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `outDir` parameter is expected to be relative to the *project* directory.

For example, suppose your `MyDaoGenerator` class is in `module1` under `projectA` and you want to generate the DAO classes into a separate `module2` of the *same* project ...

```
projectA
    module1/
        src/main/java/com.my.package/MyDaoGenerator.java
    module2/
        src/main/java/      <-- target directory
```

... the `outDir` parameter would be `module2/src/main/java`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to **change the package to this**

```
 new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, "app/src/main/java");
```

**from this**

```
new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, "../app/src/main/java");
```

Comment: so basically, just passing in the relative path to the script, instead of setting the outDir; cool. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could check the run configurations.

If your dao generator code is in a class named M.java, you can edit the run configuration for it:

[image]

Then you should ensure that it is pointing to the right working directory:

[image]

Finally, we can generate the dao code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    ...
    new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, "."); // direct to working directory
}
```

It worked for me. Hope it help.

Source: [this tutorial](http://atopeconlamaquina.blogspot.cl/2014/10/como-instalar-greendao-en-android-stuido.html)

Comment: the script ran just fine; it was determining how to set the output path of the generated source files, which the accepted answer got. but this is also a cool solution; didn't think of modifying the working directory; thanks!